# GCC with Windows SDK?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

I'm getting a lot of conflicting information on how to build native Windows apps using GCC.

Basically, I want to learn Windows programming, from a familiar standpoint. I want to learn the nitty gritty of which libraries need to be included with which headers, etc etc. So I can get some idea of the underlying implementation. I feel that visual studio takes a lot of this away with what seems to be a sometimes opaque build process *(it frustrates me that when I include the header the libraries are automatically linked, making it hard for me to see what is doing what)*

EDIT: Thanks to Ben and Serge for pointing out the falsity of the last statement. VS does not automatically include libraries based on what headers are included, rather it links a number of default libraries, regardless of what headers are included, however only functions/classes etc. required by the translation units will end up in the final executable.

Is there a way that I can develop for Windows, using the Windows API (i.e. not libc) but using a less "user-friendly" environment?

I would preferably like to stick with GCC (MinGW etc.), but I am open to other tool chains. I just want to get under a bit of that bloat and abstraction that visual studio has.

Can I just download the windows SDK and start building using MinGW? If not, where can I get the headers and libraries I need for native development? Will it compile correctly using something like minGW?

A lot of questions!

Thanks!

SUMMARY: See Serge's very helpful answer!

Thanks to everyone for the info!

Comment: MinGW already contains modified versions of the Windows SDK headers, so you should be able to get started out-of-the-box. What have you tried?

Comment: you say 'it frustrates me that when I include the header the libraries are automatically linked'. Which headers are these? In all my years of using Visual Studio it has never 'helped' me in this fashion.

Comment: For example, if I include a header (e.g. windows.h), the build process is completed with a single button. I want to have to link the libraries myself, by name, so I can really learn about the implementation. Sorry if I have got some details wrong, I haven't used VS very much.

Comment: Regarding the SDK, according to the website, it no longer ships with any build tools. But otherwise, that would be exactly the sort of thing I am looking for.

Comment: If MinGW comes with the SDK headers, do I still need to download some libraries?

Comment: Get a MinGW distribution - MinGW contains a GCC compatible version of the SDK headers and libraries.  Not MFC though. I like either http://nuwen.net/mingw.html or http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/, but there are several you can choose from. Also, you can use the VS compiler from the command line using makefiles or any IDE or editor which lets you integrate a command line compiler. Finally, you can use VS and look at the log files to see what it's doing in a build. A lot may seem hidden because it sets up projects with default settings, but you can look behind the curtain for most things.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do command line builds, nothing prevents you from writing your own [NMake](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha.aspx) file that describes what files get compiled with what flags and how they are all linked into their own executable.

The windows compiler is [cl.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s7c9wdw.aspx).

The windows linker is [link.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio, (or its free variant Visual Studio Express) do **not** automatically find the library associated to a header. Simply by default, it uses a set of standard libraries. But I can tell you that as soon as you will use less standard API, you will have to declare both headers and libraries. And if you look a little deeper in the project properties, you will find the exact command line for compilation and linking phases.

You can use either MSVC tools or MingW ones, but never try to mix them ! The object formats are not compatible with each other

EDIT :

I will now describe how it works in the version I know (MSVC Express 2008). The configuration of the project is available under `Project / Properties`. You normaly find 2 configuration here (`Debug` and `Release`) but can always add new special build configurations via `Configuration Manager`. You choose the config you want to tweek (or choose `All configurations` to apply changes everywhere.

Under `Configuration properties` you find (among others) items for `C/C++` (compilation phase) and `Linker` (link phase) with menus to tweak almost everything. Last menu is always `Command line` and gives the actual command line that will be used.

If you use another version, your mileage may vary, but I had always been able to find the configuration under `Project / Properties` on older MSVC versions ...

EDIT 2 :

Concerning the list of default libraries, they are used by the linker independantly of headers you could have used or not in your different sources. But as they are *libraries* and not *object modules*, only object modules (contained in libraries) that are actually required by the program directly or indirectly will end in the executable. I almost never used the *Ignore default libraries* option. Mainly when I wanted to be sure that I did not use a system library to reduce the size of the executable for a very special use case.

Comment: Thanks Serge. By default are all those standard libraries linked in, or is there a process whereby only the required ones are linked depending on the project (by scanning the headers, maybe?). The exact command line is exactly what I am looking for, how would I find that in the visual studio environment?

Comment: Thanks again. Great help. I can see both the C++ compiler and linker commands being used via this method. I can confirm it works the same on VS Community 2013. The linker gives these libraries by default: "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib". Are these all linked in no matter whether they are referenced by headers or not?

Comment: Upvote for taking the time to give such a comprehensive answer to all my Qs, and resolving all my miconceptions.